# Where is 'Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.' occuring

Tags: flutter

Quick question: I get this error

```
════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Is there a way to get more information to find out where the error is occurring so I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a `BuildContext` from a widget that has been deactivated. Just make sure you don't call any inherited widget (for example, `Theme.of(context)`) inside any widget's `dispose()` method and also avoid to save `BuildContext` references to then use it later since you can be using invalid contexts.